# Angular templates not showing up on main page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying out making small page templates within my main JavaScript config file for an Angular application.

The syntax appears to be sound, but whenever I display the page, I only get my pre-made menu bar and nothing else.

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Miega/mowwckze/9/**

Here's the config section of my JS file in question:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('#/homePage', {
                templateURL: 'homePage.html',
      template: '<p>WELCOME HOME!</p>'
    }).
  when('#/pCredential', {
            templateURL: 'pCredential.html',
    template: '<p>INSERT CREDENTIALS INTO NODE.</p>'
  }).
  when('#/tLogin', {
            templateURL: 'tLogin.html',
    template: '<p>PLEASE LOGIN TO THE TECHNICIAN PAGE.</p><p>GET CREDENTIALS FROM OWNER.</p>'
  }).
  when('#/aLogin', {
            templateURL: 'aLogin.html',
    template: '<p>ADMINISTRATOR ACCESS.</p>'
  })

  //load default page on page refresh
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '#/homePage'
  });
}])
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use both template and templateUrl, use one of them. Don't use #:

```
.when('/homePage', {
     template: '<p>WELCOME HOME!</p>'
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mowwckze/12/)

Comment: Issue appears to have been the unnecessary `#` character. Thanks for your help!